# Java KeyStores + Garbage Collection

Tags: java, data-leakage, memory

How does Java's Garbage Collector treat [KeyStores](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html), in terms of data lifetime? Since I couldn't find anything documented on it, should I assume it treats it like any other object, potentially copying it around memory needlessly? I'm wondering if I should use it to store cryptographic keys in memory. If I have an encrypted key and the corresponding plaintext password simultaneously in memory, it's not really providing security for me, right?

Comment: Is the focus of the question more on the KeyStore object lifetime or is it on whether holding it in memory relatively safe?

Comment: I suppose I'm asking about the KeyStore object security in general.